# ThumbDrawable of FastScrollBar is not changing.

Tags: android, android-listview, android-scrollbar, fastscroll

**EDITED**

My `ListView` is :

```
  <ListView
    android:id="@android:id/list"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:divider="#0d2e3a"
    android:dividerHeight="1dp"
    android:fastScrollEnabled="true"
    style="@style/myScrollBar" />
```

Then, in `Values` my style for `fastscrollbar` is :

```
<style name="myScrollBar" >
     <item name="android:fastScrollThumbDrawable">@drawable/fastscroll_thumb</item>
</style>
```

And, Then my `fastscroll_thumb.xml` is :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" >
<item android:state_pressed="true" android:drawable="@drawable/fast_track_drawable" />
<item android:drawable="@drawable/fast_drawable" />
</selector>
```

Where, `fast_track_drawable` and `fast_drawable` are two images.

But, my `fastscrollbar` is still not being customized. Can any one point out, where m i mistaken. i have seen some tutorials as well like [android listview fast scroll customization issue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9188364/android-listview-fast-scroll-customization-issue/22210842#22210842), And [How to show custom thumb when using fastScrollEnabled](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7059648/how-to-show-custom-thumb-when-using-fastscrollenabled)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First, remove `style` explicitly mentioned in `ListView xml`. Added the style in `value` where other styles were mentioned. Then designed the `selector`.

```
<style name="Theme.Customactionbartheme" parent="@android:style/Theme.Holo.Light.DarkActionBar">
<item name="android:actionBarStyle">@style/MyActionBarStyle</item>
<item name="android:actionBarTabStyle">@style/MyActionBarTabStyle</item>
<item name="android:popupMenuStyle">@style/PopupMenu.Customactionbartheme</item>
<item name="android:actionDropDownStyle">@style/DropDownNav.Customactionbartheme</item>
<item name="android:homeAsUpIndicator">@drawable/ic_navigation_drawer</item>
<item name="android:fastScrollThumbDrawable">@drawable/fastscroll_thumb</item>  
</style>
```

And the `Selector` is:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" >
<item android:state_pressed="true" android:drawable="@drawable/fast_track_drawable" />
<item android:drawable="@drawable/fast_drawable_orange" />
</selector>
```